# Ejemplo de proyecto con create-react-app react-router-dom y expressjs

Tags: sql-server, reactjs, express

Tengo un proyecto con create-react-app donde hago todas las rutas del proyecto con react-router-dom (ya que los ejemplos con react-router ya no son actualizados). Necesito utilizar datos de una BD en MSSQL y estoy utilizando superagent para traer los datos mediante url tipo GET.

Alguien tiene un ejemplo en el que se pueda utilizar express, junto a la app con create-react-app y que este utilizando react-router-dom?

O existe forma de traer los datos sin usar url como con superagent?

Comment: Quieres leer y escribir en la mysql sin necesidad de servicios intermedios?

Comment: Podría ser.. hay forma?

Comment: [Modulo mysql para npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) hay alternativas pero no creo que sea lo mas conveniente, en aspectos de seguridad siempre viene mejor un web service.

Comment: Entonces no es posible. Tienen algún ejemplo que haya sido publicado con el uso de estas librerías como express superagent y react-router-dom. Pero actualizado ya que muchos de los ejemplos que he visto todos están desactualizados

Comment: Todo proyecto desarrollado con React tiene que tener un servidor para poderse renderizar. Lo único que necesitas es usar el paquete [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) para comunicarte con tu base de datos a través del servidor. Ten en cuenta algo, cuando creas una SPA que es tu caso, **casi siempre** debe existir una API a la cual la SPA deba consultar.

Answer (score 2):

si lo que quieres es tener el backend y el frontend en el mismo directorio deberías agregar un `proxy` en tu package.json para que las dos aplicaciones se puedan comunicar.

[Acá](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0) hay un ejemplo y otro de la [documentación oficial](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development).

Acá también puedes ver cómo configurar express para que te deje utilizar client side routing [Configurar express con CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)

Digamos si tienes express corriendo en `localhost:8080` tu `package.json` debería tener la propiedad: `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"`

Comment: Para tenga mayor posibilidad de ser aceptada la respuesta pon partes de como agregarlo `package.json`